# How to reproduce this iPhone layout?

Tags: ios, opacity, alpha, shadow

What background color (RGB, alpha) and shadowColor, shadowOpacity should I use for the transparent plastic plate to reproduce this image setting?

My problem, that if I use less color or clearColor, there is no drop shadow, if I use high opacity color, I can't see the drop shadow under the plate.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an image, you will not be able to reproduce this same effect by code
This question should be asked to a designer and he should give you a png file that contains this image.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure you know you're asking how to reproduce soundbar plate from Apple's SpeakHere example.

Open the SpeakHere project in XCode. Then (in Project Navigator) open group "Resources".

Select file `soundbar_plate_mono.png`.

Now you can see that this is a PNG with alpha layer. Shadow is also part of the image - it's not done in code.